# Backup software of HP Lefthand P4000 storage

Tags: network-storage, lefthand

How to back up existing software and configuration of HP Lefthand P4000 series (two P4300G2 nodes in cluster running software version 9.0) storage?
We are planning to add virtual failover manager and upgrade to software version 9.5. Upgrade is planned with all iSCSI volumes disconnected from servers and we would like to be able to backup (and restore in case of upgrade failure) existing software and it's configuration (incl. replication states, etc).

Comment: Check with your HP/LeftHand support. It sounds like you're still under contract, so I would follow their guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

Lefthand doesn't have the kind of backup and restore capabilities that you are looking for. In fact, I don't think any SAN gear does.

The best you can do is document your current configuration and make sure you have current, valid backups of your data.

I can tell you from my past experience with fubared Lefthand upgrades that the upgrade manager is smarter than it looks. If a node doesn't come up right and complete it's resync then the upgrade stops. In one case I had a marginal drive that caused a slow rebuild. In the second I had a raid controller that failed a firmware update. In both cases the upgrade manager just bailed and I restated it when I corrected the problem. HP was very helpful both times.

Comment: haha the P4000 manager doesn't look very smart, but it turns out it's substantially better than it looks.